# <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?> finding path

Tags: magento-1.9, paths, help-wanted, webserver

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
```

I am searching the path in server. but unable to find Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order_totals` is the block name defined in:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/sales.xml

if you look above xml, there will code like:

```
.....

<block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">

.....
```

So call to :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
```

will render the block in your phtml. i.e

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks, It helped me :)

Comment: Welcome @Pratibha :)

Comment: What about reorder page sir ?