# Understanding <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals') ?> Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, grand-total, order-grid

I've been working into magento 1 to understand some of its concepts & relations.

I can see that the order total section in admin (re-order page) [image]

is made up of

```
<div id="order-totals" class="order-totals"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals') ?></div>
```

Is there in - **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml**
I can see this file is called in **sales.xml** with

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_data" template="sales/order/create/data.phtml" name="data">
```

I am not sure how these **(Subtotal,Gift cards,Total)** is rendered.
Actually I want to add converted base total there.

**Any thoughts from where the details are coming for these **(Subtotal,Gift cards,Total)** ?**

Comment: Please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275101/php-echo-this-getchildhtmlorder-totals-finding-path/275103#275103

Comment: The mentioned file - sales/order/totals.phtml does not gets called on reorder page.